# Getting the Steam Controller to work in the Unity Editor

Tags: unity-game-engine, input

I recently came upon some issues during development with my Steam Controller:  It was not recognized in the Unity Editor as an input device. Whatever I tried, it was not showing up in the `InputSystem.devices` array.

Through some googling I found out that Unity has to be launched through Steam. However, after adding the Unity Editor as a non-steam game and launching it through there, the problem remained: My controller was not recognized in the Unity Editor.

As archaic as this controller is, maybe someone else will run into this issue too, so I would like to share how I solved it.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem, I had to use the following steps:

1. Go to the controller settings
2. Install the 'Xbox Extended Feature Support Driver'
3. Enable Steam Input for Xbox controllers.  (Turning on the other emulation types too won't harm you)
4. Add the Unity Editor as a non-steam game.
5. Edit the Launch options (right click on Unity in library -> properties) to include `-projectPath <dir>` (**This is the crucial step to make sure SteamInput keeps running, otherwise it will stop running after launching your project from the Unity Hub)**
   [image]
6. Enable Steam Input in the Controller tab:
   [image]

If you now launch the Unity Editor through Steam (having closed your project if you had it open), your Steam status should show you are in-game. At this point, `InputSystem.devices` should contain your controller as an xbox 360 emulated controller.

Comment: Additionally, if you close the editor your steam status will still show you as playing. Close the Unity Hub if you want to get rid of that too.